# Approximately how many light years across (arclength) was the furthest reaches of the Hubble Ultra Deep Field?

Tags: hubble-telescope, deep-sky-observing

I can find the area($11^2$ arcminutes) and lengths ($200$ arcseconds per side) but if I were to consider just the furthest region (arclength) of the survey, about how many light years across would this be?

Comment: The separation between objects in light years is going to depend on the distance or redshift of these objects and what cosmological model and what values you assume for its values. The `kpc_proper_per_arcmin()` function in the [astropy.cosmology](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/cosmology/index.html) module can calculate this dimension but you will need to assume a distance and a model of the Universe e.g. the `WMAP9` model and values.

Comment: An area should be 11 arcminutes², rather than 11² arcminutes

Comment: What do you mean by "(arclength)" ?

Comment: Why is the answer not ∞?

The Hubble was not discriminate in how old or far a photon travelled.